# iPad Question : Display pdf file using CATiledLayer in iPad application

Tags: ipad

I want to display PDF file in iPad using CATiled Layer
All is well but when i use CATiledLayer in my app and run it , PDF file will display like this shown in image[image: Here i saw in iPad the top left corner full of gray color in PDF file displayed in red rounded rectangle]

Here is my Code

**For CATiled layer**

```
   tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
     tiledLayer.delegate = self;
     //Set load block of tiled layer
     tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0);
     tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000; 
     tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
```

**For drawInContext**

```
 CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
     CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
     CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
     CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
     CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
     CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
```

Please help me to solve this problem.Thank u in advance.

Comment: +1 - Good question. Will help new developer to cope with this type of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform does not scale your pdf up - you need to write your own transform code to calculate the best aspect ratio for the pdf.

Note that CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform also checks for *rotation* in the pdf, you can use sth like this to correct it manually:

```
int rotate = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(page);
    switch (rotate) {
        case 0:
            renderingSize.width = roundf(cropBox.size.width * zoom / 100);
            renderingSize.height = roundf(cropBox.size.height * zoom / 100);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, cropBox.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            break;
        case 90:
            renderingSize.width = roundf(cropBox.size.height * zoom / 100);
            renderingSize.height = roundf(cropBox.size.width * zoom / 100);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI / 2.f);
            break;
        case 180:
        case -180:
            renderingSize.width = roundf(cropBox.size.width * zoom / 100);
            renderingSize.height = roundf(cropBox.size.height * zoom / 100);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.width, 0);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI * 1.f);
            break;
        case 270:
        case -90:
            renderingSize.width = roundf(cropBox.size.height * zoom / 100);
            renderingSize.height = roundf(cropBox.size.width * zoom / 100);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, cropBox.size.height, cropBox.size.width);
            CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI / 2.f);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1, 1);
            break;
    }
```